# What is the idiomatic way in Clojure to pass a check if one of the parameters is nil?

Tags: clojure

I have a function that validates several inputs.

One of the validations checks if the interval between time1 and time2 is less than 120 seconds.

The `get-time2` function returns the value of `:time` from the database. But this value may be `nil`. Currently, this later brings a NullPointerException in the `calculate-time-diff` function.

What is the idiomatic way to make the `interval-validation?` check pass if its second argument is `nil`?

```
(defn validate-input [{:keys [time]}]
  (let [error {:errors []}
        add-error #(update %1 :errors conj %2)]
    (cond-> errors
      (validation1) (add-error "err1")
      (interval-violation? time1 (get-time2 3)) (add-error "err2"))))
```

```
(defn get-time2 [index]
  (:time (db/get-input! index)))
```

```
(defn interval-violation? [time1 time2]
  (let [time-diff (calculate-time-diff time1 time2)]
    (< time-diff 120)))
```

Is this an idiomatic solution?

```
(defn interval-violation? [time1 time2] 
  (when (and time1 time2) (< (calculate-time-diff time1 time2) 120)))
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if the `get-time2` function returns nil? The best answer is usually to throw an exception.  If you just want to ignore any `nil` values simply add an `if` statement to always return `false` if one time value is `nil`. Also, did you mean for `get-time` to be `get-time2`?.

Comment: If `get-time2` returns nil, I want `interval-violation?` not to call `calculate-time-diff` and simply return false. (Yes, I meant `get-time2`, thanks).

Comment: It's an un-written law to actually return an boolean on predicates (ending in ?) - so if you want to follow this rule, wrap your when in an boolean call. Using when+and is fine - but note, that this also does nothing for `false` (which is very likely to be fine here) in case you want to be strict about `nil` inputs...

Answer (score 2):

I would use `some?`. This returns true if not nil. It's the opposite of `nil?`

```
(defn interval-violation? [time1 time2]
  (if
    (some? time2)
    (let [time-diff (calculate-time-diff time1 time2)]
      (< time-diff 120))
    ()) ;what happens when time2 is nil goes here.
```

Alternatively, you could change get-time2 to not return nil. `get` can set a default value when the key is not found.

```
(defn get-time2 [index]
  (get (db/get-input! index) :time 0)) ;value if not found goes last
```